# How to combine multiple string in a regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to match my string using Regular Expression. Below are my string which I need to match -

```
/pp/dc/phxd/y1
/pp/dc/slcw/y1
/pp/dc/lvsr/y1

/ppuu/dc/phxd/y1
/ppuu/dc/slcw/y1
/ppuu/dc/lvsr/y1
```

And below is the regular expression I have got which works fine -

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^/(pp|ppuu)/dc/(phxd|slcw|lvsr)/y[0-9]+$");

Matcher m = pattern.matcher(string_to_test);

if(m.find()) {

}
```

Now I also need to match below string as well apart from above string -

```
/pp/dc/phxd
/pp/dc/slcw
/pp/dc/lvsr

/ppuu/dc/phxd
/ppuu/dc/slcw
/ppuu/dc/lvsr   


/pp/dc

/ppuu/dc

/pp

/ppuu
```

Is there any way to come up with single regular expression which can match all my above string?

Comment: Yes, you need to add nested `( )?` around the sections which are optional.

Comment: @user2809564 - Just a heads up, the answer you accepted is not correct.

Comment: @sln I see, can you explain me why it is not correct so that I can test it out?

Comment: @user2809564 - You have listed a complete example of cascading dependencies/options. The answer you've selected will not do that. Someone seeing this post in the future will be confused. Change your problem statement to show there is no dependencies.

Comment: For example, you could add `I also need to match /ppuu/y1 and all the other permutations`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the last three parts as optional by adding it into a non-capturing group.

```
^/(pp|ppuu)(?:/dc)?(?:/(phxd|slcw|lvsr))?(?:/y[0-9]+)?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zU7mT8/1)

`(?:..)` called [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). `?` after the non-capturing group makes the corresponding group as optional.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it into a cascade of options.

```
 # ^/(pp|ppuu)(?:/dc(?:/(phxd|slcw|lvsr)(?:(/y[0-9]+))?)?)?$

 ^ /
 ( pp | ppuu )
 (?:
      /dc
      (?:
           /
           ( phxd | slcw | lvsr )
           (?:
                ( /y [0-9]+ )
           )?
      )?
 )?
 $
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?<match>/.+)/.+");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher("str_input");
    while (m.find()) {
        String match = m.group("match");
        System.out.println(match);
        m = pattern.matcher(match);
    }
```